# PHP: how can I load the content of a web page into a variable?

Tags: php

How can I load the content of a web page into a variable?

I need to store the HTML in a string.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Provided [**`allow_url_fopen`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled, you can just use [**`file_get_contents`**](http://fr.php.net/file_get_contents) :

```
$my_var = file_get_contents('http://yoursite.com/your-page.html');
```

And, if you need more options, take a look at [**Stream Functions**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ref.stream.php) -- there is an example on the [**`stream_context_create`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) manual page where a couple of HTTP-headers are set.

If `allow_url_fopen` is disabled, another solution is to work with [**curl**][5] -- means a couple more lines of code, though.

Something as basic as this should work in the simplest situations :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://stackoverflow.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$my_var = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But note that you might need some additional options -- see the manual page of [**`curl_setopt`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for a complete list.

For instance :

- I often set **`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`**, so redirects are followed.
- The tiemout-related options are quite often useful too.

Answer (score 4):

The code below stores the content of the site w3schools.com into a variable.

```php
$my_var = file_get_contents('http://www.w3schools.com');

echo $my_var;
```